# How to replace ^@ character from a file through bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I have used `sed -i` but `sed` was not able to search the pattern `^@` in the file.

Comment: Those are null characters, i.e `\0`

Comment: can you show the input string?

Comment: It was like `123424^@^@93456`. Problem solved as suggested by 'sat'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be `^@` are null bytes. Try this `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\x00//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the characters in your file are literally `^@` then try escaping the carrot `^`:

```
sed -i 's/\^@//g' file
```

Escaping `\^` allows the pattern to continue to the next character (`@`). If you don't escape the carrot it asserts the position at start of the string, which probably isn't what you want.